# Setting a checkbox based on the button pushed in a jQueryUI Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a checkbox that when gets clicked will open up a dialog. If "Done" is clicked, I want the checkbox to have a checkmark. If "Cancel" is clicked, I want the checkbox not to have a checkmark.

Currently, I cannot get the checkbox to be set while using this code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                    var dialog = $("#test-dlg").dialog({
                            modal:true,
                            autoOpen:false,
                            buttons: {
                                    "Done": function() { $("#test-chk").attr("checked", "checked"); $(this).dialog("close"); },
                                    "Cancel": function() { $("#text-chk").removeAttr("checked"); $(this).dialog("close"); }
                            }
                    });

                    $("#test-chk").click(function(e) {
                            dialog.dialog('open');
                            e.preventDefault();
                    });
            });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="#">
            <input type="checkbox" id="test-chk" /><label for="test-chk">Testing</label>
    </form>
</body>
<div id="test-dlg">
    <p>Test Dialog</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using jQuery 1.6, so you need to use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`.

change this: `$("#test-chk").attr("checked", "checked");`

to this: `$("#test-chk").prop("checked", "checked");`

Comment: Thanks! You replied just as I found the answer here: http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/12/jquery-1-6-1-released/